# Svg and div issue

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a svg image that doesn't fit into my div. When I re-size my svg the div doesn't re-size to fit the svg. The svg should be at max size 700px and then re-size down as browser window re-sizes. I had it working with another element in Div1 that stretched the div1 to `max-width:700px`, but as I deleted that element it stopped working.

I removed the fiddle, since the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I added image tags around the svg and set the width. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an svg image it will grow as large as its container allows.
This is both in width and height.
So if the svg element looks like this: `<svg height="100%" width="100%">`
It will scale up until to its container size.

I use css to modify how to control its size:

```
.svg-class  { //put this class on your svg element
     width: 100%;
}
```

So as long as there is room in the parent containers it will grow. Now we want to limit it to 700px: Just add max-width: 700px to the size control:

```
.svg-class {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
}
```

Now it will only grow until 700px width. Even if the container is bigger.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.top {
  background-color: black;
}
.sprite {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <svg class="sprite" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="red" />
    <rect x="50" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="yellow" />
    <rect x="0" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="green" />
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="blue" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say it didn't work for me. The container div didn't resize to 700px;